# Access UILabel on RootViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to access a UILabel on the RootViewController?  I can get the RootViewController with this code:

```
var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
var vc = window.RootViewController;
while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
{
    vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
}
```

Using the debugger and stepping through the code I can see that I have the correct viewcontroller.  On that controller I have a UILabel that I'd like to set the text for, is there anyway to do that?  I'm coding in c# using Visual Studio 2022.

****** Update *******

based on suggestions from @Jason, I changed my code to:

```
var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
MyViewController vc = (MyViewController)window.RootViewController.PresentedViewController;
vc.UpdateLabel();
```

I set a break point in the `UpdateLabel()` method and it never gets called.  Not sure what's going on here, even if I was getting an entirely new instance of `MyViewController`, I would expect that I would still hit the break point.

***** Update *****

Just so folks understand what I'm trying to do, here's a more detailed explanation and more of my code.  On my View Controller I have a `CollectionView`, when the users selects options from a spinner the `CollectionView` is populated with labels that display information.  I need to update the data in another label when the user selects or deselects a cell in the `CollectionView`, in the `CollectionViewSource` I have the following code to do that:

```
public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        MyCell thecell = collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath) as MyCell;
        if (Utils.DataCheck[indexPath.Row][1] == "1")
        {
            Utils.DataCheck[indexPath.Row][1] = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            Utils.DataCheck[indexPath.Row][1] = "1";
        }
        thecell.ToggleCheckBox();

        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        MyViewController vc = (MyViewController )window.RootViewController.PresentedViewController;
        vc.UpdateLabel(); 
    }
```

The `Updatelabel()` operates on the same static `List<string[]>` in the Static Class Utils.  The `UpdateLabel()` method, when executed, does that.  I also call the `UpdateLabel()` method when I initialize the `CollectionView`, it executes just fine.  Just won't execute in the `CollectionViewSource` code.

Comment: why don't you expose a public method on the ViewController that does what you need?

Comment: I have such a method, but apparently I cannot access it.  It doesn't appear when I examine the `VC` variable.

Comment: did you cast it to the correct type?

Comment: Its a very simple method, `public void UpdateLabel()`, am I missing something?

Comment: I have no idea.  You haven't posted any of the relevant code.  But `UIViewController` does not have a `UpdateLabel` method.  You will need to cast `vc` to whatever custom type you have defined that **does** include `UpdateLabel`

Comment: @Jason I upded my code, I don't get any errors either with Intelisense or at runtime, yet the `UpDatelabel()` method never gets called.

Comment: I would expect that to work.  Are you sure `vc` is not null?

Comment: I step through the code with the debugger, it's not null.  I'm trying various tests to see if I can affect anything in the running instance.  But with the updated code I get no errors, just doesn't ececute the method.  I even tried updating the label text directly, no luck there either.

Comment: @Jason I added some more of my code and a more detailed explaination.

Comment: All of a sudden now, the line of code `MyViewController vc = (MyViewController )window.RootViewController.PresentedViewController;` returns null everytime.  I've changed NOTHING.  I cleaned and rebuilt, still returns null.  This is so frustrating.

Comment: that is generally a sign the cast is failing because the type is not correct

Comment: Sigh .. its correct.  I'm going to try another tack.  Maybe I can set an Observer on a static `UITextField`or `UILabel` in my Utils class and cause the `UpdateLabel()` to be executed that way ... just a thought ....

Comment: Well, setting an Observer didn't work.  As soon as I change the text in the field being Oserved, it locks the app up.  Lol .... of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again the solution proves to be rather simple.  In my `UICollectionViewSource` I declare a variable `private MyViewController MyParentController { get; set; }`.  When I initialize the `UICollectionViewSource` I pass in the parent viewcontroller, my `PhoneNumberSource: code:

```
public class PhoneNumberSource : UICollectionViewSource
{
    public IList<string> PhoneNumbers;
    private MyViewController MyParentController { get; set; }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return PhoneNumbers.Count;
    }

    public PhoneNumberSource(MyViewController  pMyParentController, IList<string> pPhoneNumbers)
    {
        PhoneNumbers = pPhoneNumbers;
        MyParentController = pMyParentController;
    }
    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var phoneNumberCell = (PhoneNumberCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(PhoneNumberCell.Key, indexPath);
        string phoneinfo = PhoneNumbers[indexPath.Row];
        phoneNumberCell.SetData(phoneinfo);
        return phoneNumberCell;
    }
    public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        PhoneNumberCell thecell = collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath) as PhoneNumberCell;
        if (Utils.PhoneNumbersCheck[indexPath.Row][1] == "1")
        {
            Utils.PhoneNumbersCheck[indexPath.Row][1] = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            Utils.PhoneNumbersCheck[indexPath.Row][1] = "1";
        }
        thecell.ToggleCheckBox();

        MyParentController.Updatelabel();
    }
}
```

In the View Controller I initialize the `CollectionViewSouce` like so:

```
PhoneNumberList.Source = new PhoneNumberSource(this, Utils.PhoneNumbers);
```

Label get updated every time.  And it would seem that I have access to all the methods and properties of the parent view controller.

Comment: Good job! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.